# React Native build failed on Android

Tags: android, react-native, npm, build, expo

> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-reanimated:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /home/x/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executing process /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.2/libexec/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7192f249eae24284e999d3715d8b0aff/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /home/x/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/7192f249eae24284e999d3715d8b0aff/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

[Compile error traces.jpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/km2Rx.png)

Comment: The build error is related to the React Native Reanimated, please add the package.json file along with the Node Version and JDK version you are using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.